# jsforce runTestsSynchronous not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsforce

I'm trying to run Apex tests using JSForce and it returns me the error:

```
Catch error: TypeError: classnames.join is not a function
```

I'm making a post request

```
salesforceAuthRouter.route('/playground')
.get((req, res) => {
    res.render('playground');
})
.post(async (req, res) => {
    const sfConnection = await initSFConnection();
    const message = runApexTest(sfConnection)
    res.send(message);
});
```

and the runApexTest :

```
async function runApexTest(sfConnection) {
     var testsArray = [{
        className: "SolutionTest",
        testMethods: ["findSumTest"]
    }];
    var body = {"tests": testsArray};

    logger(`body : ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);

 var message;
try {
    const result = await sfConnection.tooling.runTestsSynchronous(JSON.stringify(body));
    logger(`TEST result : ${result.body}`);
} catch (error) {
    logger(`Catch error: ${error}`);
} finally {
    return message;
}
```

}

The body log looks like this:

```
body : {"tests":[{"className":"SolutionTest","testMethods":["findSumTest"]}]}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.The errors seems like a JavaScript error. I ran the same body with Postman and it works. The org connection is established I can execute anonymous apex but just this end point doesn't work.  Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: I also tried passing just the body body without stringifying it. Still the same issue persist.

Answer (score 1):

Do not JSON.stringify. The [method](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/blob/c04515846e91f84affa4eb87a7b2adb1f58bf04d/lib/api/tooling.js#L278) is expecting two parameters, an array of class names, and a callback method.

```
var body = ['Class1','Class2','Class3'];
```

Also, jsForce doesn't use promises. You need to pass a callback function as the second parameter.

Comment: I tried passing just the body without stringifying it. Initially I setup the body according to the salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm) 

I rewrote the code to look like this. 

  `var body = ['SolutionTest'];

 sfConnection.tooling.runTestsSynchronous(body, (req, res) => {
                logger(TEST result : ${res});  });`

returning null now. Why are the documentations contradicting?

Comment: @AslahPHussain jsForce wraps the `classnames` into the proper format. I'm not familiar with jsForce; try logging all the parameters and see what you get: `(...res) => { console.log(res) }`